# SaaS practical basics and projects

Tags: cloud, saas, openstack, iaas

So i need some directions. I want to understand Cloud Software as a Service(SaaS) practical initialization. The thing is I want to create a simple cloud service which would let me run programs on this cloud from remote machine. As I understand, I need some kind of specific backbone project to start this system, similar like OpenStack or Apache Cloud for Infostructure as a Service.
Of course it may be that I understand it completely wrong and even if there is such project, it is not open source, free. I could also comprehend SaaS building on IaaS, but the thing is, I can't find any practical information at all. Could Somebody indulge me if there is any kind of free licence SaaS project or recommend a related articles or explain everything in a nut case with atleast vague direction.

Answer (score 0):

You sound like all you really want to do is create a horizontally scalable infrastructure for use in a public cloud.

http://www.slideshare.net/Clogeny/scalable-architecture-on-amazon-aws-cloud

There are many presentations and discussions about how to approach this.  I have linked one off of google that appeared to be pretty accessible.